# odoo 11 Is there any difference if we take dump from Postgres and from Odoo Backup?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

In odoo 11 which will be suggested backup and restore process,

1. Dump and restore from postgresql or
2. using Odoo to take backup and restore it.

I want to know, which process will give complete data including attachments?

Answer (score 2):

Both

1. Dump and restore from PostgreSQL

> After your dump and restore sql data you have to restore filestore
> too, you can find the filestore for your data base, by default windows: `C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo\filestore\database_name`, linux: `/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/database_name`. Restart your odoo server and reload your browser.

2. using Odoo to take backup and restore it.

> In `Backup Database` wizard you should select `zip(includes filestore)` option.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

- Odoo Backup can include all of your attached files as well (your
  "filestore" directory)
- Odoo Backup may only be restored from your last Odoo Backup so all data entered since that point is lost forever.
- PostgreSQL does not back up your "filestore" so no attachments are backed up.
- PostgreSQL can "log ship" your database so that you can roll-back a database in case of disaster

If you have an experienced PostgreSQL administrator, is makes sense to have a proper backup/log shipping setup in PostgreSQL.

If you want to spin up a test server, using Odoo Backup can be very helpful; just restore the backup to a test server.  Note:  you must ensure that the test server is not connected to the internet.

My company uses both methods of backup together for provide a more robust solution.